# How do I get rid of a miscellaneous quest objective in the journal without using setstage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed the quest "Drowned Sorrows" a while ago, and I recently noticed that my journal still has the miscellaneous quest objective: "Find out about Isabelle Rolaine in Winterhold." This is probably because I went straight to Hob's Fall Cave without speaking to Haran or Vex first.  I've tried using `resetquest` and `setstage` for all the quest stages.

I've also tried using the `say` command to get Haran to say the dialog which would normally clear this objective, but I can't get that command to work.

Are there any console wizards out there who can help me?

Comment: What is that particular piece of dialogue you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a solution, I stumbled upon a mod that could help you out, called [Quest Eraser](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26660), by user *kryptopyr*:

> This mod will remove various quest objectives from your journal.
>
> When activated, certain quest objectives will be removed from your
>   journal. You are given the option to remove all of the qualifying
>   quest objectives or to remove only some of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!  I've been playing vanilla Skyrim so far, because I've read about a lot of bugs that have arisen from using mods.  Maybe I need to find my courage and start modding. . .

Comment: Using mods doesn't necessarily mean your game will be buggy: some can be installed and removed haphazardly without consequence. Just be mindful of scripts and load order, check the reviews, and use mod installation software like Mod Organizer. And if this answer solved your problem, be sure to check it as such. Thanks.